# Contact Java client from a Hazelcast node

Tags: java, hazelcast

I have a hazelcast cluster that performs several calculations for a java-client triggered by command-line. I need to persist parts of the calculated results on the client-system while the nodes are still working. I am going to store parts of the data in Hazelcasts maps. Now I am looking for a way to inform the client that a node have stored data inside the map and that he can start using it. Is there a way to trigger client operations from any hazelcast-node?

Comment: Can you post some code that shows what your trying to achieve ?

Comment: Yes please look up the `MapStore`, perhaps it can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several paths to solve the problem. The most simple one is using a dedicated IMap or any other of Hazelcasts synchronized collections. One can simply write data in such a map and retrieve/remove it after it got added. But this will cause a huge Overhead, because the data has to be synchronized throughout the cluster. If the data is quite big and the cluster is huge with a few hundred nodes all over the world or at least the USA, the data will be synchronized over all nodes just to get deleted a few moments later, which also has to be synchronized. Not deleting is no option, because the data can get several gb big, which will make synchronization of the data even more expensive. The question got answered but the solution is not suited for every scenario.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not very clear, but it looks like you could use `com.hazelcast.core.EntryListener` to trigger a callback that will notify the client, when a new entry is stored in the data map.

Comment: I stumbled over this feature just a few minutes after the post of my question. It looks like it is exactly what I need. I will try it in a test-environment and post the code here or ask further questions. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You member node can publish some intermediate results (or just notification message) to Hazelcast `IQueue`, `ITopic` or `RingBuffer`.
A flow looks like this.

1. a client registers a listener for, say, rignbuffer.
2. a client submits command to perform on the cluster.
3. a member persists intermediate results to the `IMaps` or any other data structure
4. a member sends a message to the topic about the availability of partial results.
5. a client receives messages and accessing data in `IMap`.
6. a member sends a message when it's done with it's task.

Something like that.
You can find some examples [here](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast-code-samples/tree/master/distributed-topic)

Let me know if you have any questions about it.

Cheers,

Vik